# Is there a way in Jint to store a function to a Func?

Tags: c#, jint, dynamic-code

I am using Jint to dynamically run functions for my C# code. It works perfectly for running the functions. However the execution time is linear per execution

```
var engine = new Jint.Engine();
var rule = File.ReadAllText("file.js");
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
  engine.Execute(rule);
}
```

I am going to be running the functions potentially upwards of 1million times. Currently this code takes 126197ms (2minutes 6s) to run! Is there a way to store the function in C# after it's been read by the engine? Or is there another library that would handle this number of executions in a faster timeframe?

**EDIT**

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
var engine = new Engine().Execute("function() { /* code here */}");
var method = (Func<TypeOne, TypeOne, ResultType>)engine..

var result = method(paramOne, paramTwo);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried parallelization?

Comment: Haha mate!! I've spent a day and a half looking through ways to dynamically run code.. completely forgot about C# itself.. Thanks!!

Comment: Still not finding the perfect solution in this but works for now, only divides the time by the number of processes running unfortunately!